# .htaccess Blocking Useragents AND IPs AT THE SAME TIME not working

Tags: .htaccess, blocking

How do I block Useragents and IPs AT THE SAME TIME?
Currently using this

```
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "Chrome/80" good_ua
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "Chrome/81" good_ua
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "Chrome/82" good_ua
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "Chrome/83" good_ua

order deny,allow
deny from all
allow from env=good_ua
```

That white lists those UAs. But when I try adding this code

```
deny from 1.1.1.1
deny from 1.0.0.1
```

only blocking UA works, I can not make them both work at the time. I need to block IPs and allow certain UAs.